# mysql most count for each country two tables

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

For a statistic i want to show the "best producer" for each country.
There are two tables: dog and owner. In owner there is the Country in dog are all other nessecary. I count how often dog.id is father id.

For one country specified i do with

```
    $result = mysql_query("
    SELECT 
    dog.father_id,  dog1.id, dog1.dogname, dog1.owner_id, dog.date_of_birth,
    COUNT(dog.father_id) anzahl,
    owner.country_short
    FROM 
    dog

    LEFT JOIN dog as dog1 ON
    (dog.father_id = dog1.id)
    LEFT JOIN owner  ON
    (dog1.owner_id = owner.id)

    WHERE dog.father_id !=0     
    AND dog1.date_of_birth >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 10 YEAR)


    AND owner.country_short ='de'


    AND owner.kennel_note =''
    GROUP BY 
    dog.father_id
    ORDER BY 
    anzahl DESC 
    LIMIT 3

     ", $db) OR die(mysql_error());

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    { ....
```

How can I do for each country (take automatic from database)?
Solutions with SET @ will give me a parse error.
Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: I'm guessing u are afther the [Group By](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) statement for this

Comment: additional group by country_short give me only 3 (LIMIT) results, but not for each country